# Error Handling with Koa and routing-congrollers

Tags: typescript, koa, koa2, koa-router

I am looking for a a solution of a generalised error handing when using the library [routing-controllers](https://github.com/typestack/routing-controllers).

My custom error handling should be able to catch any rejected `Promise`s coming from the `Controller`, build a response body from it and sets the HTTP code according to the type of the error on the response. I do not like the Koa default error handling, as I want to spit out my custom response body (not stack trace, etc...).

On a simple setup like described in the [example](https://github.com/typestack/routing-controllers#example-of-usage) with passing the `Controller` on the initialisation of the app it is not longer possible to use a Koa error handling described in the [Koa wiki](https://github.com/koajs/koa/wiki/Error-Handling).

In detail, I set up the app like:

```
const app = createExpressServer({
   controllers: [UserController]
});
app.listen(3000);
```

and try to add an error handler the following way:

```
app.use(async (ctx, next) => {
  try {
    await next();
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err)
  }
});
```

I am not sure if I am doing something wrong or those two approaches are just not compatible. In case of the latter: Does anyone has a solution to the outlined problem?

Comment: I think you have to disable the default error handler your router provides.

Comment: @thesearentthedroids, unfortunately this is only true for express, when I do this for koa an error its thrown on the actual error and the handler does not kick in.